# Spring boot controller redirect view

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have problems redirecting to a view after validating some data.

Ajax call

```
    function validarClave(){
    var matricula = $('#matricula').val();
    var fecha_creacion = $('#fecha_creacion').val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "/apolo/recuperar/validar",
        data: {
            "matricula" : matricula,
            "fecha_creacion" : fecha_creacion
        },
        success: function(result) {
            // 
        },
        error : function(e) {
            //
        }
    });
   }
```

in the controller try two ways to redirect, but it seems that it does not work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/recuperar/validar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String validarRecuperacionClave(
    @RequestParam("matricula") String matricula,
    @RequestParam("fecha_creacion") String fechaCreacion,
    RedirectAttributes flash) throws ParseException {

String dateStr = String.valueOf(fechaCreacion);
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date dt = sdf.parse(dateStr);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
Usuario usuario = usuarioService.buscarPorMatriculaFechaCreacion(matricula, dt);
if (usuario == null){
    flash.addFlashAttribute("error", "error");
    //return "redirect:/recuperar/recuperar-clave";
    return "/recuperar/recuperar-clave";
}
flash.addFlashAttribute("usuario", usuario);
//return "redirect:/recuperar/nueva-clave";
return "/recuperar/nueva-clave";
}

@GetMapping("/recuperar/nueva-clave")
public String recuperarNuevaClave(Model model){
    return "/recuperar/nueva-clave";
}
```

this shows me the developer tool

[image]

[image]

in the preview tab the view to which you should redirect

[image]

Comment: You are doing the request with some ajax calls so, you have to redirect in the `success`/`error` callback in the JavaScript code.

Comment: have you tried to return with appending redirect like `return "redirect:/recuperar/nueva-clave";`

Comment: @lealceldeiro but how would RedirectAttributes in the success towards the other page

Comment: @Jayesh if I tried, is as commented